# Type 'TimeZone' has no member 'local' in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nstimezone

I am converting project developed in Swift2.3 to Swift3.0 using Xcode8 Beta4. In which I have method to convert date to string, but it fails to convert it.

```
class func convertDateToString(_ date:Date, dateFormat:String) -> String?
{
    let formatter:DateFormatter = DateFormatter();
    formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.local
    let str = formatter.string(from: date);
    return str;
}
```

[image]

Also in documentation there is no member named `local`.

Is there any way to use `TimeZone` directly ? or we have to use `NSTimeZone` ?

Comment: try this formatter.timeZone =.local

Comment: `NSTimeZone.local` works, same for `.system` and `.default`. You could file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : `.local` also not working.

Comment: @technerd - I searched in google I am not get teh dcoument realted to this , may be martin comment also fine to follow

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Trying to find solution, If not then will file bug. By the way thanks Kartik.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Find solution for now, Find answer below, if any suggestion then also comment it on answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By going deep into class hierarchy,have found `NSTimeZone` as `public typealias`, which open up access of `NSTimeZone` for us.

Inside `TimeZone`

```
public struct TimeZone : CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible, Hashable, Equatable, ReferenceConvertible {

    public typealias ReferenceType = NSTimeZone
}
```

So by using below syntax error get disappear.

So below code will work.

For **local** time zone.

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.local
```

For **default** time zone.
Use `default` with same syntax.

```
formatter.timeZone =  TimeZone.ReferenceType.default
```

For **system** time zone.
Use `system` with same syntax.

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.system
```

**Swift 3**

You can use `.current` instead of `.local`.

```
TimeZone.current
```

Comment: just use `NSTimeZone.local` tor Local, `NSTimeZone.default` for default and `NSTimeZone.system` for system

Comment: @LeoDabus: Yes, we can use `NSTimeZone` directly, but when Xcode automatically convert Swift2.3 code into Swift3.0 then it convert `NSTimeZone` to 'TimeZone'. So it recommends to use Swift Classes. So If any one want to use `TimeZone` then it will cause problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Use this instead of `.local` in swift 3:

```
TimeZone.current
```